# Assembling two images with shift in vertical and horizontal direction

Tags: image-processing

I want to assemble two gray scale images of 100*100 pixels.

- From image two 30 pixels at the left border should be deleted and the
  remaining image shoud me shifted 10 pixels down.
- After that image 1 and the modified image 2 should be assembled in row.

---

```
img1 = Image[Array[0.3 &, {100, 100}]]
```

[image]

```
img2 = Image[Array[0.8 &, {100, 100}]]
```

[image]

How can the following code be improved/replaced?

**Instead of using `ImageData` (as I did it) I would like to know if a solution exists with image functions like `ImageCompose` or others.**

```
xshift = 30;
yshift = 10;

img2Data = ImageData[img2];
img3Data = Array[0 &, {100, 100 - xshift}];

img3Data[[1 + yshift ;; 100, 1 ;; 100 - xshift]] = 
        img2Data[[1 ;; 100 - yshift, 1 + xshift ;; 100]];
assembledImage = ImageAssemble[{img1, Image[img3Data]}]
```

[image]

Comment: What is wrong with the code? Does it not do what you want? What improvements are you looking for?

Comment: @MarcoB: Instead of using `ImageData` (as I did it) I would like to know if a solution exists with image functions like `ImageCompose` or others, which would be much faster since I have to process thousands of image pairs this way (my original png images are of 1600*1200 pixels).

Comment: @mrz Have a look at `ImageTake` in the documentation. This does what you want on an Image level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear[trim]
trim[image_, xshift_, yshift_] := 
   ImageTrim[
      image,
      {{xshift + 1, yshift + 1}, ImageDimensions[image] + {-1, yshift - 1}}, 
      Padding -> Black
   ]

ImageAssemble[{img1, trim[img2, xshift, yshift]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This works using `Image*` functions, but on my system it is not faster than your approach, rather surprisingly. However, I am not intimately familiar with the `Image*` functions, so perhaps a better solution exists.

Comment: thank you for the solution ... I will test it on my original images

Comment: Your solution is definitely faster than my code and a great improvement. For the comparison I used 100 gray scale png Images of 1600*1200 pixels, whereby `xshift=95` and `yshift=11`. On my computer `AbsoluteTiming` of your solution gives about 50 sec and my code needs about 77 sec.

Comment: @mrz Glad to hear that, and thank you for the accept!